# Time Complexity of Euclid Algorithm by Subtraction

Tags: time-complexity, euclidean-algorithm

```
 int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    while(a!=b)
    {
        if(a > b)
            a = a - b;
        else
            b = b - a; 
    }

    return a;
}
```

What is the time complexity of this algorithm? Can someone provide a detailed explanation?

Comment: This algorithm never terminates if a = 1 and b = 0.

Comment: @templatetypedef nope, for Euclid Algorithm by Subtraction, `a` and `b` must be positive integer numbers.

Comment: @Anatolii Wouldn't it be trivial to modify the algorithm to handle one of the inputs being zero?

Comment: @templatetypedef Sure, you're right, but I do not know what exact requirements the OP has. At least, the OP could use an `unsigned` type for parameters and function return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Euclid Algorithm by Subtraction, `a` and `b` are positive integers.

The worst case scenario is if `a = n` and `b = 1`. Then, it will take `n - 1` steps to calculate the **GCD**. Hence, the time complexity is O(max(a,b)) or O(n) (if it's calculated in regards to the number of iterations).

By the way, you should also fix your function so that it validates whether `a` and `b` are really positive integer numbers. Or even better, you could change your return and parameter types to `unsigned long` or `unsigned int` or similar and, as suggested by @templatetypedef, handle cases for `a = 0` or `b = 0` separately.